# What class to add to buttonset elements to show select status after a group select action?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a toolbar of checkboxes that are grouped together via a `buttonset()` call.  If one checkbox is selected, I'd like to set the entire group to selected, and deselect on a second click event.

I have this click handler instanciated

```
$("#category_all").click(function(e){

  if ($("#category_1").is(":checked")) {
    $(".category_selector").prop("checked", false);
    $(".category_selector").removeClass("ui-state-active");

  } else {
    $(".category_selector").prop("checked", true);
    $(".category_selector").addClass("ui-state-active");
  }
});
```

The check state change is applied to all buttonset elements, but the rest of the elements maintain the same styling.  I've also tried "checked" for the class, but no result.

What is the jQuery UI class to be added to the buttonset group to show that they are all selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the refresh method after setting the checked property.  This is outlined in the docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-refresh)